# Is it possible to save data in another process with a C# app?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
p.StartInfo.FileName = "notepad.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "somefile.txt";
p.Start();
```

When "somefile.txt" is opened in notepad, its text will be modified. I want to save the new text in a temp file with the C# app automatically. 
Is it possible to access this text and save it with C#?

Comment: Do you want to access the saved file after the process is closed?

Comment: No, I want to access the text in notepad while it is opened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is sorta possible, you could use P/Invoke to call the SendMessage() method and generate the WM_COMMAND messages for the Edit + Select-All and Edit + Copy menu commands.  That puts all text on the clip board, readily accessible to your program.  You'll need to use the Spy++ utility to find out what the command identifiers are.  Looks like 25 and 769 when I look at it on Win7.

There's a more direct way to discover the commands.  In Visual Studio choose File + Open + File and select c:\windows\notepad.exe.  Open the Menu node and double-click the "1" resource.  That opens the menu editor, select Edit + Select-All and look at the Properties window for the ID.

Of course, this technique is specific to Notepad.  The command IDs will be different for another program.  As will be the code you need to find the proper window handle.  Using Process.MainWindowHandle is treacherous at best, you don't know what specific instance of the process you need to select.

Answer (score 3):

It would be very difficult to look at the text in-memory in the notepad process. It could be done, but it depends on the internal memory layout of notepad and your process may need administrative privileges depending on how the memory pages are protected.

Why not use a FileSystemWatcher to detect when the file has been modified, and then read the file in directly using c#?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Copy the somefile.txt before you start notepad to a temporary file/folder. Start notepad using this temporary file. And wait for Notepad to exit.

Then you can examine if the file is changed (checksum?).

Probably delete the file after the processing, or your system will be full with temp files.

Answer (score 0):

You can bring notepad window to front and send CTRL+S. You will need to use pinvoke for that.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand why you would want to use notepad?

If you need a user to edit a text file, and then your app take some action on the text itself, why not just give the user the ability to edit the text right in your app?

What does notepad give you that the TextBox control doesn't have?

Try something like this

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

TextBox myEditor = new TextBox();

myEditor.Multiline = true;
myEditor.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
myEditor.AcceptsReturn = true;
myEditor.AcceptsTab = true;
myEditor.WordWrap = true;

// Get the text from the file.
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("SomeFile.txt"))

myEditor.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: It's because I have a USB device that writes data automatically in any opened notepad window. PC is left alone saving that data.